# AngularUI modal to be draggable and resizable

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an angularUi modal window wrapped in a directive:

html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div my-modal="{ data: 'test2'}">test2</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap', 'myModal']);

angular.module("myModal", []).directive("myModal", function ($modal) {
    "use strict";
    return {
      template: '<div ng-click="clickMe(rowData)" ng-transclude></div>',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        rowData: '&myModal' 
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.clickMe = function () {
            $modal.open({
            template: "<div>Created By:" + scope.rowData().data + "</div>"
                        + "<div class=\"modal-footer\">"
                        + "<button class=\"btn btn-primary\" ng-click=\"ok()\">OK</button>"
                        + "<button class=\"btn btn-warning\" ng-click=\"cancel()\">Cancel</button>"
                        + "</div>",
            controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
                $scope.ok = function () {
                    $modalInstance.close({ test: "test"});
                };

                $scope.cancel = function () {
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                };
            }
        });
        }
      }
    };
});
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/yzxtWwZQdq94Tagdiswa?p=preview

I want to make the modal draggable and resizable. I searched through the internet and was able to find the following solution for implementing draggable:

http://plnkr.co/edit/jHS4SJ?p=preview

This is the important part:

```
app.directive('dragable', function(){   
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link : function(scope,elem,attr){
      $(elem).draggable();
    }
  }  
});
```

but was not able to make it work with my example. Can someone help me with this? I wonder is it possible to use jqueryui modal wrapped in a directive (instead of bootstrap) ? I am not very good at javascript and will be very greatefull for any working example with both options. Thanks

EDIT:

I added jqueryui reference and managed to make the modal draggable by adding this line:

```
 $(".modal-dialog").draggable();
```

The problem is that I am not sure when to add this line. In the moment I have added this in the cancel method (just to make it work):

$scope.cancel = function () {
                      $(".modal-dialog").draggable();
                };

So when the modal is opened I need to call cancel and only then the modal is draggable. If I call it earlier the .modal-dialog does not yer exist. Suggestions?

updated plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/yzxtWwZQdq94Tagdiswa?p=preview

I am missing something little, can someome provide working example ?

Comment: You would need to import jquery into your code, as $() is recognized by jQuery rather than angularjs

Answer (score 17):

I've created a native directive to make the modal draggable. You only need AngularJs and jQuery. The Directive uses the "modal-dialog" class from Ui-Bootstrap modal and you can only move the modal in the header.

```
.directive('modalDialog', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'AC',
    link: function($scope, element) {
        var draggableStr = "draggableModal";
        var header = $(".modal-header", element);

        header.on('mousedown', (mouseDownEvent) => {
          var modalDialog = element;
          var offset = header.offset();

          modalDialog.addClass(draggableStr).parents().on('mousemove', (mouseMoveEvent) => {
                $("." + draggableStr, modalDialog.parents()).offset({
                    top: mouseMoveEvent.pageY - (mouseDownEvent.pageY - offset.top),
                    left: mouseMoveEvent.pageX - (mouseDownEvent.pageX - offset.left)
                });
            }).on('mouseup', () => {
                 modalDialog.removeClass(draggableStr);
            });
        });    
     }
  }  
});
```

Comment: where to declare this directive? This doesn't work: `<div class="modal-header" modal-dialog>
                <span class="modal-title">Some Title</span>
        </div>`

Comment: you don't have to declare the directive just need to register it in your project and when you use ui-bootstrap modals it just works because the ui-bootstrap modal has the "modal-dialog" set for its own in the "background". When you have a working default ui-bootstrap modal then you only need to register this directive in your project.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solution worked for me. I tried a couple of others, they didn't work 100% correctly.

Comment: Good solution but ... it makes use of ECMAscript 6 syntax. In my case it broke the pdf generation of webpages by wkhtmltopdf.org which is based on Webkit (QtWebKit) which seems to not support ECMAscript 6. The issue is pretty simple to fix by replacing all 3 occurrences of '(event) => {...}' by 'function(event){...}' but it was hard to find out ...

Comment: this answer should be accepted as solution. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to modify built-in templates you can write a directive that targets `modalWindow`:

```
.directive('modalWindow', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      link: function(scope, element) {
        element.draggable();
      }
    }  
  });
```

Please note that you will have to load both jQuery and jQuery UI *before* AngularJS scripts.

**NOTE**: Also keep in mind that newer versions of Angular UI bootstrap have been prefixed with "uib" so "modalWindow" becomes "uibModalWindow" with thanks to @valepu

Comment: Does the native Angular `draggable` implementation also work?  I have not been able to get it to work with modal.

Comment: You have a typo in your answer @pkoziowski.opensource

Comment: it should be "element.draggable()". Also keep in mind that newer versions of Angular UI bootstrap have been prefixed with "uib" so "modalWindow" becomes "uibModalWindow"

Answer (score 6):

I combined the two above answers and made my modal dragable.

```
.directive('modalWindow', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      $(".modal-dialog").draggable();
    }
  }  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

an Angular UI modal with a draggable title bar

NOTE: have to load both jQuery and jQuery UI before AngularJS scripts.

```
angular.module('xxApp')
    .directive('uibModalWindow', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            link: function (scope, element) {
                $('.modal-content').draggable({handle: ".modal-header"});
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your examples. I little bit polished your code and this is my final result. to my solution it works perfectly :-)

HTML:

```
<div class="draggableModal ui-widget-content">

   <div class="modal-header">
     ...    
   </div>
</div>

angular.module('posProductsManager').directive('modalDialog', function () {
    var definition = {
        restrict: 'AC',
        link: function ($scope, element) {
            var draggableStr = "draggableModal";
            var header = $(".modal-header", element);
            var modalDialog = element;

            var clickPosition = null;
            var clickOffset = null;

            header[0].addEventListener('mousedown', function (position) {

                clickPosition = position;
                clickOffset = position;

                window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpEvent);
                window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveEvent);
            });

            function mouseUpEvent() {
                clickPosition = null;
                window.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpEvent);
                window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveEvent);
            }

            function mouseMoveEvent(position) {

                var offset = modalDialog.parents().offset();

                $("." + draggableStr, modalDialog.parents()).offset({
                    left: clickPosition.pageX + (position.pageX - clickPosition.pageX) - clickOffset.offsetX,
                    top: clickPosition.pageY + (position.pageY - clickPosition.pageY) - clickOffset.offsetY,
                });

                clickPosition = position;
            }


        }
    };

    return definition;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$(elem).closest('div.modal-dialog').draggable();
```

in link function