# Angular resizable popup

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a popup that fits to the width of a browser. However, I would like the user to be able to resize and/or reposition the popup modal.

We are using a modal similar to the pattern described in the Angular documentation: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Is there an example of an angular popup modal that can be dragged/resized?

Could someone post a jfiddle example?

Comment: you may want to consider fleshing out your question slightly;  This could be interpreted as a request for off site resources and put on hold as off topic.

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22201539/angularui-modal-to-be-draggable-and-resizable may help you in some way.